# Allowing unix user 'postgres' access to external .pm files for plperlu

Tags: perl, postgresql, centos, file-permissions, plperlu

I'm porting a Windows perl/postgresql web app to CentOS.

In `postgresql.conf` I have these lines:

```
custom_variable_classes = 'plperl'              # list of custom variable class names

plperl.use_strict = on

plperl.on_plperlu_init = 'require "/path/to/my/app/dev/area/MyModule.pm";'
```

In Windows 2003, this allowed me to put `use MyModule;` in plperlu functions in PostgreSQL, and they would work, provided I had gone to the path with the .pm files and changed the ACLs to give user `postgres` "Read" and "Read & Execute" permissions in the Security tab.

On CentOS 6.4, I'm a bit confused.  When I try to define a plperlu function calling MyModule, it gives me `ERROR:  Can't locate /path/to/my/app/dev/area/MyModule.pm in @INC`.

I'm confused because MyModule.pm is owned by me:me, and had 664 perms.  I tried 665 and still no luck: `sudo -u postgres ls -l /path/to/my/app/dev/area/MyModule.pm` reports `Permission denied`.  As far as I thought I understood unix permissions, 665 means that 'other' has permission to read and execute.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just wrote this up and realized I had recently learned the answer.

Unlike our Windows setup, Linux needs permissions from all directories along the path.  So I started doing ls -l on the path, and shorter and shorter.  It was 644 all the way up until near the top, where I had a 700.  I did chmod 705 (also chmod 701 worked, I switched to that after) on that, and bingo, `sudo -u postgres ls` could see it, and so could my plperlu function definition.

Comment: Actually, Perl just needs execute access, not read access.  For directories, read access lets you get a directory listing, and execute access lets you access files by name.  Since Perl is looking for a specific filename, it doesn't need to get a directory listing.  So `chmod 701` would have worked, too.